# Electron vue app - using private repo to update app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, github, electron, environment-variables

I'm trying to use electron auto updater feature in my app. The publishing process works fine, I've configured my `vue.config.js` file correctly and inside a `.env` file I have my token stored. The problem is whith the bundled app, it will not open and will show a blank screen because to check for update it need the github token. I don't want to ship the token with the app source code and I don't have idea of how to solve this problem. Can anyone suggest me a reilable solution? I've read [this old github](https://github.com/iffy/electron-updater-example/issues/14) issue but my vue electron app stop working if I obfuscate the code.